# What's the meaning of "Fairytale meets beat meets counterculture"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, syntactic-analysis

The first sentence of the article [The brilliance of Richard Brautigan](https://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2014/sep/23/prose-poetry-brilliance-of-richard-brautigan) by Sarah Hall reads as follows:

> Fairytale meets beat meets counterculture: bursting with colour, humour and imagery, Brautigan’s virtuoso prose is rooted in his rural past – and that’s what draws me in

In another part of the text we can read the following:

> Surrealism meets folk meets scat?

What's the explanation and meaning for a structure of the type "X meets
Y meets Z"?

English is not my native language.

Comment: It means “a mashup of C, Y, and Z”, or “a potpourri of X, Y, and Z”, or most simply, read the verb *meet* in those contexts as *plus*.

Comment: A juxtaposition of those three things, with no real implication that the result is good or bad.  (Note that "beat", in this sense, refers to the "beat culture" of "beatniks".)

Comment: Research might  have shown that "X meets Y meets Z" means roughly, "X overlaps with Y overlaps with Z". Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

It means that what you're describing has been created by combining some or all of the individual qualities of X, Y and Z together. X, Y and Z are often unrelated or even opposed to one another; the points of connection among them are usually not apparent; and the result of the combination is typically unique.

To me, "X overlaps Y overlaps Z" describes a different situation, where X, Y and Z might be similar or related; and the points of connection among them might be defined, apparent or even obvious.